# How to derive a typescript type from the graphql introspection results?

Tags: typescript, graphql, react-admin, introspection

In a react-admin app, I have a dataProvider based on `ra-postgraphile`. In a custom component, I want to query that dataprovider using a record type for more type safety. I intend to do that according to the [tip described in their documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#usedataprovider-hoo), like so:

```
dataProvider.getOne<Product>('products', { id: 123 })
//                  ^^^^^^^ the record type
    .then(({ data }) => {
        //     \- type of data is Product
        // ...
    })
```

How do I create the `Product` type based on the types in the introspection results of the IntrospectionQuery?

Actually I do not even know how to get the introspection results from within a component that react-admin renders in the first place.

Here's the type from the types array in the introspection results that describes Product.

```json
{
  "kind": "OBJECT",
  "name": "Product",
  "description": null,
  "fields": [{
      "name": "nodeId",
      "description": "A globally unique identifier. Can be used in various places throughout the system to identify this single value.",
      "args": [],
      "type": {
        "kind": "NON_NULL",
        "name": null,
        "ofType": {
          "kind": "SCALAR",
          "name": "ID",
          "ofType": null,
          "__typename": "__Type"
        },
        "__typename": "__Type"
      },
      "isDeprecated": false,
      "deprecationReason": null,
      "__typename": "__Field"
    },
    {
      "name": "id",
      "description": null,
      "args": [],
      "type": {
        "kind": "NON_NULL",
        "name": null,
        "ofType": {
          "kind": "SCALAR",
          "name": "UUID",
          "ofType": null,
          "__typename": "__Type"
        },
        "__typename": "__Type"
      },
      "isDeprecated": false,
      "deprecationReason": null,
      "__typename": "__Field"
    },
    {
      "name": "productCode",
      "description": null,
      "args": [],
      "type": {
        "kind": "NON_NULL",
        "name": null,
        "ofType": {
          "kind": "SCALAR",
          "name": "Int",
          "ofType": null,
          "__typename": "__Type"
        },
        "__typename": "__Type"
      },
      "isDeprecated": false,
      "deprecationReason": null,
      "__typename": "__Field"
    },
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "description": null,
      "args": [],
      "type": {
        "kind": "SCALAR",
        "name": "Datetime",
        "ofType": null,
        "__typename": "__Type"
      },
      "isDeprecated": false,
      "deprecationReason": null,
      "__typename": "__Field"
    }
  ],
  "inputFields": null,
  "interfaces": [{
    "kind": "INTERFACE",
    "name": "Node",
    "ofType": null,
    "__typename": "__Type"
  }],
  "enumValues": null,
  "possibleTypes": null,
  "__typename": "__Type"
}
```

Comment: After I asked the question I realised the end goal I was after is not making sense. TypeScript only performs static type checking at compile time. The IntrospectionQuery is done during runtime and I don't plan to (or know of a way to) run the introspection query during compilation. So I'm simply going to call the dataProvider without the type. I'm going to leave this question open, since there may be a useful context where an answer to it might be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own graphqlProvider.
i am using schema preloading Introspection it as context to my provider

```js
get-graphql-schema http: // localhost: 8557 --json -> src \\ dataProvider \\ Core \\ schema.json
```

there is no dynamic access based schema in my projects, so this approach is optimal for me.